# Database advantages? Access, MySQL, msSQL, or any others?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, ms-access

Dear all Stackoverflowers,
I just started to learn programming and now I'm putting this question online based on a quote: *no question is silly*

My work needs to develop a order system based on web, which wants a database system. Since using Excel for years as a general office user, I naturally turn this to Access. However, most people say Access is very limited comparing to MySQL or MSSQL, or any other more professional database system.

But after developing some functions for my company's order system, I really find Access can fulfill my request. And I also tried MSSQL to develop, which I found it not quite convenient to use.

I have searched in stackoverflow and find no general answer about my doubt. Now I am sincerely hoping some experienced and professional developers could clear my doubts.

Now I'm listing some Access advantages, which I don't think other database system have. I hope you could help me also find these advantages in others.

```
1. Access is portable, I can just copy a xxx.accdb file to my company and continue with development.
2. Access is easy to generate helpful table, for example, it will automatically generate a field that can automatically count, could be used as primary key value.
3. it is more compatable with Excel, to display and filter data.
4. importantly, it nerely needs no environment to setup, just needs MS Office to be installed. 
............others
```

However, I also find some points that MSSQL is advantaged:

```
1. security reasons
2. easy to backup, ( just use BACKUP..... sql statement to do it)
3. can edit stored procedure to save some functions to database
...............others
```

specifically, I wish some friends could tell me how to make other database portable? since I usually work both at home and in office. It's a headache to move MSSQL work to my office, since the version of MSSQL is not the same.

Thank you all and best regards, :)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While it's true no question is silly, it's equally as true that not every question is right for every audience. This question isn't appropriate for SO, because it's open-ended and calls for discussion and opinion. Questions here should be specific and answerable, not discussions. Please take a few moments to read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq), especially the part on what questions should (and should not) be asked here. We try really hard to keep things on-topic and appropriate here, so the site remains a good resource for answers. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

## Microsoft Access

I've never used Access, but the main disadvantage I'm aware of is that you *have to have local filesystem* access, which means:

- You need a shared filesystem
- Someone with write access can delete everything
- It probably doesn't have very good multi-user performance due to file locking

(Someone correct me if I'm wrong about this)

## Microsoft SQL Server

This is a pretty nice solution. I used it for several years and found it to be good in most cases.

- Pretty good performance
- Comes with a nice GUI (SQL Server Management Studio)
- Integrates with Microsoft's domain logins (useful if you have Exchange I think)
- There is a free version, but the non-free version is extremely expensive

## MySQL

I don't recommend MySQL. PostgreSQL and SQL Server are both better in pretty much every way.

- Good performance in some cases, extremely bad performance in others (terrible query planner)
- Large community so it's easy to get help and tools
- Free

## PostgreSQL

- Consistently good performance (able to use multiple indexes, has the best query optimizer I've ever used)
- Somewhat arcane syntax in some cases and fewer tools (less new-user friendly)
- Free

## Conclusion

Since you're already firmly in the Microsoft camp, I'd just go with SQL Server, unless you're worried about price, in which case I'd go with PostgreSQL. Access is an option that may be easier upfront, but I think you'd end up regretting it.

Comment: SQL Server and what? Access is a database management tool that normally uses a Jet/ACE database and often enough with SQL Server. Any answer to what to use instead of Access needs to include a suggested front-end that includes a reporting tool.

Comment: MySQL is not always free : just read license http://www.mysql.com/about/legal/licensing/index.html